# Calling a function from a module in ES6

Tags: javascript, module, es6-modules

I have a js module and import it into the main js app.

The js module has its own function/method.

However when I try to call that method from the main js app, I get the eslint error:
`'testMethod' is defined but never used`

test.js:

```
export default function test() {
  console.log('foo');
  function testMethod() {
    console.log('bar');
  }
}
```

app.js

```
import test from './test';

test.testMethod();
```

eslint error: `'testMethod' is defined but never used`

console error: `Uncaught Error: Module build failed: Module failed because of a eslint error`

Comment: The given code will not work in vanilla ES6 syntax. You are not providing the entire architecture. Please tell us what build system you are using.

Comment: `export function testMethod(`. And then from client. `import {testMethod} from ".\test"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining a function called `testMethod` which is enclosed in the scope of the `test` function. The `testMethod` function is never called in the scope in which it exists.

The `testMethod` function isn't exported, and is not visible outside the scope it is defined in (the enclosing function).

Based on your example in `app.js`, it looks like you want to export an object, one of whose properties is the `testMethod` function from `test.js`, rather than a function. Compare with the following:

```js
// test.js
export function testMethod() {
 return "Hello";
}

// app.js
import { testMethod } from './test';
// or
import test from './test';

console.log(testMethod());
console.log(test.testMethod());
```

Answer (score 2):

`testMethod` is a function inside `test` function. It is not a property of the exporting `test`function.
If you need the inside `testMethod` function, you can export an object

```
export default {
  testMethod: function() {
    console.log('bar');
  }
}
```